# Cardinality of the unit square and union of sets of size $c$ are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So this is a simplified version of the theorem where union of sets of cardinality $c$ has cardinality $c$. $c$ refers to the **continuum**.

We try to prove instead the union of sets of cardinality $c$ has the same cardinality as the unit square which we also know is size $c$.

So we want to define a bijection between these two sets.

There was another textbook that I answered before proving this it was showing that:

$|[0,1] \times \{r\}|=|S_i|$ where for each $i \in [0,1], |S_i|=c$.

So I defined a bijection such that $|[0,1] \times \{r\}|=|S_i|$.

How can I make use of the bijection I defined in this question to assist me in defining a bijection for the union of sets of size $c$ to the unit square?

Comment: A union of sets of cardinality $c$ can have cardinality  (much) greater than $c$.

Comment: You also need a limit on _how many_ sets of size $\mathfrak c$ you're taking the union of. If there are more than $\frak c$ of them, then there is no reason the union would have cardinality $\mathfrak c$.

Comment: There are $S_i$ of them (taking the union of) for all $i \in [0,1]$, sorry I'm not sure if that answers your question as I am new to this sort of topic. So I think there are exactly $c$ of them?

Comment: @javacoder: What is $S_i$?

Comment: I am only given that for each $i \in [0,1]$ $S_i$ are sets of cardinality continuum. And am trying to show $\cup{i \in [0,1]} S_i$ is equal to the cardinality of the unit square, in particular trying to define a bijection between these two sets with the use of the previous question in the textbook which I stated in the post. I hope that clears up things, sorry once again.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The union of sets with cardinality $c$ does, in fact, have cardinality $c$. the idea is that while we know that this union has cardinality greater than or equal to $c$(like we have been taught), it is easy to prove that this union also has cardinality less than or equal to $c$. And then, we can deduce by the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem, that $ \vert U \vert = c$, where $U$ is the union of all sets with cardinality $c$.

Comment: How many sets are there in the union? Your argument is flawed if there is no control on the number of sets in the union.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to first clarify what $S$ or $S_i$, for that matter, particularly is.

Please read my comment in reply to KaviRamaMurthy in the comments as you will have to use that result in establishing your proof. A proof of it can be found online or if you post it as a separate question, I will gladly prove it for you.

Now that we have established that the cardinality of the union of sets with cardinality $c$, let's call this union $U$, does indeed have cardinality $c$, we can proceed further. The idea is that you have to establish a one-to-one correspondence or bijection between the unit square/circle and the closed interval $[0, 1]$ which is fairly easy to do so(Now you have, in a way, already shown that both the cardinality of the unit square and union of sets of size $c$ are equal as they are $c$ but that is not the point of this proof). Now, here you can use the *Enumeration principle* to show that each element of the set of the union of sets with cardinality $c$ can be labelled by the closed interval $[0, 1]$. By doing all of the above, you will have shown that the cardinality of the unit square and union of sets of size $c$ are equal. Hope that helps and you are able to finish PS3 on time. If not, feel free to contact me directly.